# Finding the MIN() value of a SUBSTRING()

Tags: mysql, max, min

I'm having the following problem. Imagine my mySQL table looks like this:

```
id   range
1    210-400
2    300-310
3    100-350
```

I want to find

1. the MIN value of the first part (before the "-") in the range field
2. the MAX value of the second part (after the "-") in the range field

Now i tried to select the needed parts of that field with SUBSTRING and then get the MIN or MAX value like this:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`,'-',1) as `left_value`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`,'-',-1) as `right_value`,
  MIN(`left_value`),
  MAX(`right_value`)
FROM `table`
```

But i just get "#1054 - Unknown column 'left_value' in 'field list'"

So my question - **is this even possible**, and **how**?

Comment: And this, class, is why storing multiple values in one field is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma after your 3rd line (after `as 'right_value'`).

However, this probably still won't completely solve your problem.  +1 for Devart's answer.  To expand, you're probably looking for something closer to this:

```
SELECT
  MIN(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`, '-', 1)),
  MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`, '-', -1))
FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 3):

Use SUBSTRING_INDEX twice - in the MIN and in the MAX functions, or use subquery because aliases are not accessible in current SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

As Devart described, you can't use "aliased" column names, but with MySQL, you can use SQL variables... maybe adjust to something like

```
SELECT
      @leftValue := SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`,'-',1) as ignore1,
      @rightValue := SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`,'-',-1) as ignore2,
      MIN(@leftValue) as LowRange,
      MAX(@rightValue ) as HighRange
   FROM 
      `table`,
      ( select @leftValue := '', @rightValue := '' ) SqlVars
```